# If $1!+2!+\dots+x!$ is a perfect square, then the number of possible values of $x$ is?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, square-numbers

If $1!+2!+\dots+x!$ is a perfect square, then the number of possible values of $x$ is?

I looked for a general way of expanding such a factorial series but I was not able to find one, without that I don't know any other way to approach this problem.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Think modulo $5$.

Comment: This seems like a cool question. Not sure why it's attracting downvotes (except that attitudes on this site aren't always very good.)

Comment: I don't think people think there's anything wrong with the question, just the way it's being presented. For example, the actual question isn't even in the body, only in the title.

Comment: Sorry,I was not aware of that. I have seen many questions presented like this.

Comment: A lot of questions on this site are posed poorly. Yours isn't that bad, and I surely wouldn't downvote it, but don't take examples from other questions. Refer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) instead

Comment: I agree with @goblin some of our attitudes here arent that good....Downvoting answers and questions ..for no reason...when these questions bring life to the website

Comment: And please, downvoters, if you DO decide to downvote a question: explain WHY in the comments so the OP can improve!

Comment: @goblin Up and down voting here is a bit arbitrary. But ideally, votes should never reflect the problem itself, but rather the presentation of it (you can see the tooltips when you hover over the voting buttons). "Does not show research effort" is by far the most common reason to downvote, and it applies to a LOT of the questions we get. This question shows a bit more research effort than the ones I bother to down vote, but there still isn't much there.

Comment: (cont.) Personally, I would at least expect someone to calculate, before they come here, the first seven or eight factorials explicitly (that's still small enough that you can do most of the calculations in your head), and from there the pattern that they all end in $3$ would be apparent (although its significance may not be as easy to catch). That is the kind of question that would earn an upvote from me. Saying what is effectively "I stared at it for a while but nothing dawned on me" doesn't really help us write helpful answers.

Comment: @goblin I perfectly do agree. There are LOTS of questions that are really interesting. Maybe the are not really difficult or "brain teasing", but who cares? Down votes here appear to be VERY arbitrary. People down vote sometimes just because they find the question boring, useless or "too easy". I'm in accord to say that some questions are, but I NEVER down voted a question though. Why? Because when I (like other people) ask a question it's because I am interested in other people's way to reason, in the answer and in acquiring knowledge / methods. Down votes are stupid. Expect for wrong answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $$a_n = \sum_{j=1}^nj!$$

Knowing that for $j\ge 5$, the term $j!$ will end with $0$, since the product will contain both $2$ and $5$ it should be straighfroward for you to show that
$$a_n = 33 + \sum_{j=5}^n j!$$

This sum therefore ends with digit $3$.

**Big Hint**

> It is easy to check that no perfect square can end with digit $3$ (namely by checking all squares $\mod 10$). This shows that $a_n$ is not perfect square for $n\ge 4$.